# Dropdownlist in asp.net mv3 without using razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a collection iEnumerable in my model which contains multiple product objects.
Product object has fields like id,name cost,etc.

I want to create a dropdownlist in view of product ids without using razor.

Comment: Meaning you don't want to do @Html.DropdownListFor?

Comment: Yes i don't want to use @Html.DropdownListFor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can manually generate the html by iterating over your product collection.  Would that work for you?

```
<select name="ProductId" id="ProductId">
@foreach(var p in Model.Products) {
    <option value="@p.Sku">@p.Description</option>
}
</select>
```

EDIT:  With the aspx / webforms view engine

```
<%if(Model.ProductCollection!=null) {%> 
    <select name="ProductId" id="ProductId">
         <% foreach (var p in Model.ProductCollection) {%> 
            <option value="<%:p.Id%>"> <%:p.Id%> </option> 
        <% }%> 
    </select> <% 
}%>
```

Comment: I am trying to something like this. But the below code is not working.

<%if(Model.ProductCollection!=null) 

          {%> 
       
                                 <select name="ProductId"         id="ProductId">
<%   
              foreach (var p in Model.ProductCollection)
              {%> 
    <option value=<%p.Id%>> 
 <%p.Id%> 
    </option> 
<% 
              }%> 
</select> 
<% 
          }%>

Comment: It looks like you are using the regular aspx view engine and not web forms?  I have added an example of that to the answer.